# What is a challenge password?

Tags: ssl, csr

I'm setting up SSL on an Ubuntu server. One of fields it asks for as part of setting up the CSR is a "challenge password".  What is that?  The default is blank.  Do I need to enter one?

Answer (score 179, accepted):

And now at the top, by popular request, the *TL;DR* bit:

The challenge password requested as part of the CSR generation is not the same thing as the passphrase used to encrypt the secret key. The challenge password is basically a shared-secret nonce between you and the SSL certificate-issuing authority, embedded in the CSR, which the issuer may use to authenticate you should that ever be needed.

---

The old, full answer, because *reasons*:

The "challenge password" requested as part of the CSR generation, is different from the passphrase used to encrypt the secret key (*requested at key generation time, or when a plaintext key is later encrypted - and then requested again each time the SSL-enabled service that uses it starts up*).

Here's a key being generated, and the beginning of the generated key:

```
$ openssl genpkey -algorithm rsa -out foo.key
............++++++
...++++++

$ head -3 foo.key
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIICdgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCAmAwggJcAgEAAoGBAJ9jNAG4Noy//r/S
eeK/gEgGOV0BZm0CYmgSQGj4P6N3cJsPlGsG80qKTxTFwoEiXnM3BVeBpDdXhGKt
```

This key has no passphrase.  I wasn't prompted for one at creation, and haven't entered one.  Now, let's generate an encrypted key:

```
$ openssl genpkey -algorithm rsa -des3 -out bar.key
...........................................++++++
.....................................++++++
Enter PEM pass phrase:
Verifying - Enter PEM pass phrase:

$ head -3 bar.key
-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
MIICxjBABgkqhkiG9w0BBQ0wMzAbBgkqhkiG9w0BBQwwDgQInfwj1iv3icMCAggA
MBQGCCqGSIb3DQMHBAizMHBklBexiwSCAoDtRKf1WtMiVMH7HraGTIG0rlQS6Xuj
```

So it should be clear what an encrypted private key (which apache, or any other SSL-enabled server, will need unlocking for it when it starts) and a plaintext private key (which doesn't require unlocking at service start time) look like.  Now I'll generate a CSR **with** a challenge password from the **unencrypted** key:

```
$ openssl req -new -key foo.key
You are about to be asked to enter information that will be incorporated
into your certificate request.
What you are about to enter is what is called a Distinguished Name or a DN.
There are quite a few fields but you can leave some blank
For some fields there will be a default value,
If you enter '.', the field will be left blank.
-----
Country Name (2 letter code) [XX]:
State or Province Name (full name) []:
Locality Name (eg, city) [Default City]:
Organization Name (eg, company) [Default Company Ltd]:
Organizational Unit Name (eg, section) []:
Common Name (eg, your name or your server's hostname) []:
Email Address []:

Please enter the following 'extra' attributes
to be sent with your certificate request
A challenge password []:asdfasdf
An optional company name []:
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----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-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
```

And just to show that the key hasn't magically become encrypted:

```
$ head -3 foo.key
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIICdgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCAmAwggJcAgEAAoGBAJ9jNAG4Noy//r/S
eeK/gEgGOV0BZm0CYmgSQGj4P6N3cJsPlGsG80qKTxTFwoEiXnM3BVeBpDdXhGKt
```

So I say again: the "challenge password" requested as part of the CSR generation is **not** the same thing as a passphrase used to encrypt the secret key.  The "challenge password" is basically a shared-secret nonce between you and the SSL certificate-issuer (aka Certification Authority, or CA), embedded in the CSR, which the issuer may use to authenticate you should that ever be needed.  Some SSL certificate-issuers make that clearer than others; look [down at the bottom of this page](https://web.archive.org/web/20150516233421/http://www.ebizid.com/support/generating-ssl-csr/csr-creation-index.php) to see where they say the challenge password is needed - it's **not** when you restart apache:

> Should you choose to enter and use a challenge password, you will need
> to make sure that you save that password in a secure place. If you
> ever need to reinstall your certificate for any reason, you will be
> required to enter that password.

Comment: Is there a difference between an "SSL Issuer" and a CA (Certificate Authority)?

Comment: I don't think so; would you prefer that I used the alternative term?

Comment: Technically they aren't issuing the SSL protocol itself, but rather a SSL compatible certificate. I feel like SSL issuer is less clear. SSL Certificate Issuer would be clear, in my humble opinion.

Comment: @JonathanLeaders ok, I have so changed it.  Hope that's better, and thanks for helping clarify matters.

Comment: Very (very) complete answer, when one wasn't needed IMHO. Based on the question asked, you could eliminate all of your answer except that following 'The "challenge password" is basically a shared-secret nonce...'. I believe that would have answered the question asked just as completely, with less distracting non-pertinent information.

Comment: @joe thanks!  What you can't see (because you don't have the rep) is that I was responding to a since-deleted earlier answer by a very highly-rated user (who was in this case, unfortunately, wrong) so had to do a point-by-point rebuttal.  Its subsequent deletion, which was not done by its author, does make mine look a little odd, but until now I've chosen to let it stand.  If enough others support your viewpoint by upvoting your comment, I'll amend my answer.

Comment: Namecheap support are telling me that the challenge password is only needed for  certificate on IIS an server. Is that true? (it sounds odd)

Comment: @AlistairMacDonald I have no idea (sorry), knowing nothing about IIS.  It does sound odd, though.

Comment: I was baffled by this very same question, and found this answer not that helpful for my limited understanding of the subject (due to the way it is written), but fortunately found my answer from https://security.stackexchange.com/a/77082/67048

Comment: @MadHatter When generate CSR, how to turn off or avoid asking "challenge password" ?

Comment: @ChamindaBandara that's a completely different question; feel free to ask it as one.